# How to properly load a Starlark script into another?

Tags: bazel, buck, skylark, starlark

I'm trying to make a very simple implementation with [Starlark](https://github.com/bazelbuild/starlark):

**greeting.bzl**

```
def greet():
    print ("Hello World!")
```

**test.bzl**

```
load (":greeting.bzl", "greet")

greet()
```

And execute it with:
`java -jar Starlark_deploy.jar test.bzl`

The result of the above call is:

```
file ':greeting.bzl' was not correctly loaded. Make sure the 'load' statement appears in the global scope in your file
```

*My end goal is to have my own Starlark engine, which depends on `Starlark_deploy.jar`. I'll then leverage the existence of Bazel rules (such as `htt_archive` and `http_file`) and define my own Starlark superset.*

---

I'm using Bazel java implementation for Starlark [described in the official documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/starlark/blob/master/users.md). It was obtained by:

1. Cloning [Bazel repository](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel)
2. Running `bazel build //src/main/java/com/google/devtools/starlark:Starlark_deploy.jar`
3. The output of the command above is `Starlark_deploy.jar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not documented because it's not a clean or stable API. Expect API changes in the future. To embed in another tool, the [Go implementation](https://github.com/google/starlark-go/) is much more mature.

That being said, if you want to experiment, you can:

```java
import com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.ParserInputSource;
import com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.ParserInputSource;
import com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.StringLiteral;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

  public Environment newEnvironment(Map<String, Environment.Extension> imports) {
    return Environment.builder(mutability)
        .useDefaultSemantics()
        .setGlobals(Environment.DEFAULT_GLOBALS)
        .setEventHandler(PRINT_HANDLER)
        .setImportedExtensions(imports)
        .build();
  }

  public Environment execute(String path)
      throws InterruptedException, IOException, EvalException {
      String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)), CHARSET);
      ParserInputSource input = ParserInputSource.create(content, PathFragment.EMPTY_FRAGMENT);
      BuildFileAST ast = BuildFileAST.parseSkylarkFileWithoutImports(input, PRINT_HANDLER);
      Map<String, Environment.Extension> imports = new HashMap<>();
      for (StringLiteral imp : ast.getRawImports()) {
        imports.put(
            imp.getValue(),
            new Environment.Extension(execute(imp.getValue())));
      }
      Environment env = newEnvironment(imports);
      ast.eval(env);
      return env;
  }
```

The returns the environment after execution, so you can inspect the variables or functions that have been defined.

In the example above, modules are loaded one by one in the `for` loop. You may do the evaluation in parallel, like Bazel does.

As I said before, expect breaking changes in the API.

Comment: That's great. I'll be cautious in regarding to using that in prod but I definitely want to test it. I'll give it a try and come back the acceptance of the answer! Thank you very much for the help :)